# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, nuget

When I type "dotnet build" the following error occurs:

```
CSC : error CS8032: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators.LoggerMessageGenerator 
cannot be created from /Users/xuz1/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions/6.0.1/analyzers/dotnet/roslyn3.11/cs/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators.dll : 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.. 

Build FAILED.

CSC : error CS8032: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators.LoggerMessageGenerator 
cannot be created from /Users/xuz1/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions/6.0.1/analyzers/dotnet/roslyn3.11/cs/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators.dll : 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
 The system cannot find the file specified..
```

I tried to add the package using:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis --version 3.11.0
```

but it gives me this error:

```
error:   nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I would like to confirm which version of the Visual Studio you are using? In Visual Studio, go to `Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` and run the command `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`. After that build your project and try to run it. See whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Solved the issue by changing microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions version to v3.1.9 since I am using .net core version 3.1

Comment: I am glad that you found the fix for the issue. I would like to suggest you post your solution as an answer to this question. After 48 hrs, you could try to accept your own answer to this question. It may help other community members in the future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by changing microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions version to v3.1.9 since I am using .net core version 3.1